# Extracting and joining strings with boost::algorithms::join

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, stl, stl-algorithm

I have a collection of a certain struct, and I want to join a string member of each of these structs into a semicolon-separated list. Making good use of the standard algorithms library and Boost, the problem breaks down easily:

1. Use `std::transform` to get a collection of the strings, then
2. Call `boost::algorithm::join` to join them together.

However, making a copy of the strings just to feed them to `join` is silly, so I attempted to use a `reference_wrapper` around the strings as the output for `std::transform`.
The corresponding code can be seen here:

```
struct IPAddress {
    vector<uint8_t> binaryValue;
    string stringValue;
}

// ---snip---

vector<IPAddress> addresses;

// Populate and manipulate the addresses vector
// ---snip---

// Join the list.
vector<reference_wrapper<string>> addressStrings(addresses.size());
transform(begin(addresses), end(addresses), begin(addressStrings),
    [](const IPAddress& addr) {
        return ref(addr.stringValue); // Expodes
    });

return boost::algorithm::join(addressStrings, ";"); // Also explodes
```

The lambda provided to `std::transform` fails to compile, claiming that there is no match for the assignment operator between two `reference_wrapper<string>`s, despite that being [documented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator%3D) and the entire point of a `reference_wrapper`.

Then, if I comment out the `transform` call, `boost::algorithm::join` fails anyways by trying to call a default constructor of `reference_wrapper` (which has none) instead of `string`.

Am I missing something straightforward, or should I just give up and use a `for` loop with iterators?

Comment: Construct a boost range from each string and pass them to join

Comment: @PorkyBrain I don't think that "shallow" ranges can be mutable, which is required for `join`. So, that would lead to copying the values, which clearly is what the OP is trying to avoid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little help from boost ranges you can have your cake and eat it.

It removes the sting from this mix: the complication is that you want to use an intermediate collection of `std::string const&` but, obviously that doesn't work with `std::vector`.

So, we drop the intermediate collection, instead using an *adapted view* (`boost::adaptors::transformed`) and, no need for a lambda either[¹], just use `std::mem_fun`: See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7316fc15615f9d6)**

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

struct IPAddress {
    std::vector<uint8_t> binaryValue;
    std::string stringValue;
};

std::string foo(std::vector<IPAddress> const& addresses)
{
    using namespace boost::adaptors;
    return boost::algorithm::join(
        addresses | transformed(std::mem_fn(&IPAddress::stringValue)), 
        ";");
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<IPAddress> const addresses {
        { {}, "test1" },
        { {}, "test2" },
    };

    std::cout << foo(addresses);
}
```

Prints

```
test1;test2
```

---

[¹] unless `stringValue` was an overloaded member function